# If $\mathcal{E}$ is a family of subsets of $\Omega$ then there is a unique $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}$ over $\Omega$

Tags: probability, measure-theory

If $\mathcal{E}$ is a family of subsets of $\Omega$ then there is a unique $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}$ over $\Omega$ such that:

i) $\mathcal{F}$ contains $\mathcal{E}$.
ii) If $\mathcal{G}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra over $\Omega$ that contains $\mathcal{E}$, then $\mathcal{F} \subset \mathcal{G}$

Well I don't know how to prove this but I have thinking that maybe there is a way if I note that $\mathcal{F} = \sigma(\mathcal{E})$ and then see that 
$$\mathcal{F}=\sigma(\mathcal{E}) \subset \mathcal{G}.$$

Then $\mathcal{F}$ contains $\mathcal{E}$

Someone could help me to prove the second statement, please. Thanks for the help and time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $\mathcal{F} := \sigma(\mathcal{E})$ is the $\sigma$-algebra you are looking for. By the very definition, $\sigma(\mathcal{E})$ is the **smallest** $\sigma$-algebra containing $\mathcal{E}$; this means that for any $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{G}$ containing $\mathcal{E}$ we have $\sigma(\mathcal{E}) \subseteq \mathcal{G}$ - and that's exactly (ii).

Comment: yea, I forgot that. Thanks.

Comment: @Knight You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Take $\sigma(\mathcal{E})$ to be the intersection of all sigma-algebras that contain $\mathcal{E}$.

This is a pretty generic pattern in mathematics, let $\mathcal{F}$ be a family of sets satisfying some property $P$ that is closed under arbitrary intersection (i.e. if $\mathcal{G} \subset \mathcal{F}$, then $\cap_{A \in \mathcal{G}} A \in \mathcal{F}$). Then for a set $S \subseteq X$, the smallest set that satisfies $P$ generated by is necessarily the intersection of all elements in $F$ that contain $S$. This shows up a lot: the sub-group $H \leq G$ generated by a set of group elements $S \subset G$; the convex hull of a set $S \subset \mathbb{R}^d$; the sigma-algebra generated by $\mathcal{E}$ in your example, etc.